# Creating multiple SD cards with varying config

Tags: sd-card

I have a base config that I am happy with. The distro is Raspbian.

I would like to create 10s of this same SD card with some subtle differences to each card image.

For example, I would like to set the hostname of each device in sequence. For example: `pi-1`, `pi-2`, `pi-3` etc..

Is there a way I can script this stuff? Ideally I want a script that runs and will update whatever variables I want. It will then write to the SD card inserted, prompt me to replace the SD card with a new fresh one, press return to continue.

Is this possible or should I take the pain. Dupe a bunch of cards and manually edit the hostname?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get your point but if the changes are not really complicated: Why don't you just write *one* image to *all* cards and script the *changes*?

Here would be some example Python code for the automated hostname changes:

```
import os

number_cards = 9001

for card_id in number_cards:
    # Write to SD card
    os.sys("dd bs=4M if='/home/yourname/masterimg.img' of='/dev/sdXX'")
    # Mount SD card
    os.sys("mount /dev/sdXX /media/temp")
    # Do changes...
    hostname=open("/media/temp/etc/hostname","w")
    hostname.write("pi-"+str(card_id))
    hostname.close()
    # Unmount SD card
    os.sys("umount /dev/sdXX")
    # Prompt for next card
    ignore = raw_input("Card "+str(card_id)+" modified succesfully. Please insert next card and get another coffee.")
```

Of course you would not have an image of every card afterwards but if the changes are minimal you can save gigs of space for tens of cards.

Comment: This will only do half the job. If you do not also set the name in `/etc/hosts` (which `raspi-config` does) you will get strange "Not Found" error messages when attempting some networking.

Comment: @Milliways Good to know. I did it my way (though manual instead of automated) and did not encounter problems so far. I will change the hosts file in my applications. Anyway, my code is just a basic example that should provide the general idea of such an automated mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I use a `bash` script to set `hostname` on the Pi itself on 1st boot. This can be read from a file, or generated.

NOTE The other answer may work (I haven't tried it) BUT only does half the job. If you do not also set the name in `/etc/hosts` (which `raspi-config` does) you will get strange "Not Found" error messages when attempting some networking.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to set Pi hostname based on MAC (or Serial number)
# 2017-08-18
# This script should be run as root (or with sudo) to change names
# If run by a user it will report changes, but will NOT implement them
# Works for PiB (all models), Pi2, Pi3, PiZeroW with on board networking
# PiA models will set a unique Name based on Serial number

PDIR="$(dirname "$0")"  # directory containing script
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)
# Find MAC of eth0, or if not exist wlan0
if [ -e /sys/class/net/eth0 ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
elif [ -e /sys/class/net/enx* ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/enx*/address)
else
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)
fi

# NOTE the last 6 bytes of MAC and CPUID are identical
CPUID=$(awk '/Serial/ {print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/^0*//')
echo "Current Name" $CURRENT_HOSTNAME
echo "MAC" $MAC
# If you want to specify hostnames create a file PiNames.txt with MAC hostname list e.g.
# b8:27:eb:01:02:03 MyPi
# If not found a unique Name based on Serial number will be set
NEW_HOSTNAME=$(awk /$MAC/' {print $2}' $PDIR"/PiNames.txt")
echo "Name found" $NEW_HOSTNAME
if [ $NEW_HOSTNAME == "" ]; then
    NEW_HOSTNAME="pi"$CPUID
fi

if [ $NEW_HOSTNAME = $CURRENT_HOSTNAME ]; then
    echo "Name already set"
else
    echo "Setting Name" $NEW_HOSTNAME
    echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
    sed -i "/127.0.1.1/s/$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$NEW_HOSTNAME/" /etc/hosts
fi
```