# Pi running dnsmasq can't resolve own hostname

Tags: sudo, dns, pi-b

I have a Pi 1 B running dnsmasq as name server for my home network. This setup works great for me and has been much more stable than letting my Asus router handle it.

Lately – however – I have noticed a problem: The pi can't resolve its own hostname unless I specify the full domain.

```
$ ping pihostname
ping: unknown host pihostname
$ ping pihostname.mydomain.lan
PING pihostname.mydomain.lan (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

It can find other computers on the network without the domain (but the domain is not expanded):

```
$ ping otherhostname
PING otherhostname (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
$ ping otherhostname.mydomain.lan
PING otherhostname.mydomain.lan (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Other computers can find the pi without the domain (and here the domain is expanded):

```
$ ping pihostname
PING pihostname.mydomain.lan (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): 56 data bytes
```

This leads to an error message every time I use the sudo command on the pi:

```
$ sudo echo hello
sudo: unable to resolve host pihostname
[sudo] password for myusername: 
hello
```

Any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: I assume you changed the hostname, but the question is HOW?

Comment: @Milliways In /etc/hostname. (Note: There was an error in the original question, the last output has been edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only did half the job. If you had changed using `raspi-config` it would have worked. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53893/8697 or edit `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I was so sure this was dnsmasq related that I didn't even bother to look at /etc/hosts.